# SharePoint 2013 My Sites User Name With a Space Issue Double Encoding of space %20 becomes %2520

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-userprofile

I have an issue regarding the links generated for User's My Sites, unfortunately all the users on the domain that will use SharePoint have a space in their user name i.e. 'Joe Bloggs'.
This means that when their 'My Site' is created it has the url http://mysites.abc.com/Personal/Joe Bloggs

The issue i am having is that when the user clicks the 'Sites' or 'Sky Drive link in the top right hand corner of our root SharePoint site the url http://mysites.abc.com/Personal/Joe%2520Bloggs

Does anyone know how i can do any one of the below:
 - Prevent double encoding of the space.
 - Force SharePoint to create user 'My Sites' Without a space.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Richard